How can I find the timestamp of a 1-minute clip in a 33-hour recording?
I have a 1-minute audio clip and a 33-hour recording. I need to locate the specific timestamp of this clip in the long recording. Is there a tool or method to match the audio and find the timestamp automatically? Something like Shazam or other audio matching apps, but with audio files.

I'm not aware of any software that does this. The way it could be done is write a short script for a computational language like Matlab (free: Gnu Octave) or Python (with a signal processing library). The idea is to load both files and do a cross correlation operation between them. The resulting output could be scanned for the peak value, which would be the location of the match. It might be useful to downsample the audio files to some much lower sampling rate like 1kHz first, so the cross correlation runs faster. You could learn more about this by asking in the Signal Processing SE.

Depending on the type of audio, something like a gapper could reduce the 33 hours to a smaller amount to go through

What type of recording is it? Is it mostly silence with some sound here and there? You could try a spectrogram and try to find the matching timestamp
